# Java - Android - Main thread exception uploading by FTP

Tags: java, android, upload, ftp

I'm developing a very simple app in which you press a button, the camera is launched, you take a photo and this photo is stored in the SD card and then uploaded to my FTP. I'm using simpleFTP library to connect to my FTP but I don't know why I'm getting the error below when uploading the file.

This is the relevant part of the code from the main class:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            Log.v("photoFile", photoFile.toString());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }

}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //The image is already stored in the phone, let's open it up from there
        File imgFile = photoFile;
        if(imgFile.exists()){

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }

        new UploadFTP<File>().doInBackground(imgFile);
    }
}
```

And this is the class that handle's the AsycnTask:

```
class UploadFTP<File> extends AsyncTask<File, Void, Void> {


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(File... params) {
    File file = params[0];
    try
    {
        SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();

        // Connect to an FTP server on port 21.
        ftp.connect("ftp.myurl", 21, "myuser", "mypass");

        // Set binary mode.
        ftp.bin();

        // Change to a new working directory on the FTP server.
        ftp.cwd("www/xxx");

        // Upload files.
        ftp.stor(new java.io.File(String.valueOf(file)));

        ftp.disconnect();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
 }
}
```

And here the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ignistudios.photosharing, PID: 22214
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.ignistudios.photosharing/com.ignistudios.photosharing.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3607)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3650)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
    Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:590)
    at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
    at org.jibble.simpleftp.SimpleFTP.connect(SimpleFTP.java:68)
    at com.ignistudios.photosharing.UploadFTP.doInBackground(UploadFTP.java:26)
    at com.ignistudios.photosharing.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:139)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3603)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3650) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using your `AsyncTask` the wrong way. Call `execute` on it and it automatically call `doInBackground()` on a different thread, where network operations are allowed.

```
UploadFTP uploadFTP = new UploadFTP();
uploadFTP.execute();
```

Comment: Great!! Thak you very much. Now it seems to work, such a silly error :( However, no I'm getting another error: java.io.IOException: SimpleFTP received an unknown response when connecting to the FTP server: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------  Could be a problem with the settings of the server?

Comment: @Gosdi, That sounds like problem with the server or the API (SimpleFTP) you are using. If my answer helped you solving the initial error, please upvote it or mark it as an answer